# Argument out of range exception for decimal SQL Server EF C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

I am either going crazy or missing something entirely here. I have a time entry I am trying to submit with a "TimeWorked" attribute whose data type in the SQL server is decimal(4,2).

When I try to add a time entry with 10.00 as the value for TimeWorked, I get the following error.

**Error**

[image]

**Code To Insert**

```
using (var context = new ProjectTrackingDb())
{
    TimeEntry entry = new TimeEntry
    {
        ProjectName = SelectedProject.ProjectName,
        Phase = SelectedProject.Phase,
        Code = SelectedClassification.Code,
        TimeWorked = TimeEntry.TimeWorked,
        Description = TimeEntry.Description,
        UserName = CurrentUserName,
        Date = TimeEntry.Date
    };
    context.TimeEntries.Add(entry);
    context.SaveChanges();  
}
```

**Database Model**

```
[Table("TimeEntry")]
public partial class TimeEntry
{
    [Key]
    public int EntryID { get; set; }

    public decimal TimeWorked { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Phase { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

**Database data types:**

[image]

**What I have tried:**

I have tried a few things. I tried adding a Range(0,10) data annotation to the model for the database. I increased the precision of the decimal to (18,4) just to see if it would accept it.

I was able to manually insert a value of 10 into the database directly in SSMS so I am not quite sure how that is working but my code to insert does not?

**Edit**

I also tried adding 10 directly to the timeworked attribute from my code and it still threw the error. I am inspecting the data before inserting and it shows up as 10 as well.

Comment: instead of `TimeWorked = TimeEntry.TimeWorked` have you tried `TimeWorked = 10` and see if it works?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` instead of `IndexOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: Yes the same thing happens. I even debugged the data before it hit and it also said 10. I literally have no idea why this is happening right now.

Comment: Might be I'm not exactly sure which it is.

Comment: Codefirst or DB First?

Comment: Code first. Although I was editing the decimal range in the db when trying to debug this

Comment: My gut says it's that you are using Dec(4,2) and .NET will want to treat it as dec(18, 2) by default. Thus you need to add the .Precision and / or .Scale properties. But I can't test it right now to validate the hypothesis.

Comment: I'll try and do as you suggested and override the default. I'll update the question with what I find.

Comment: Maybe the problem is how the EF is mapping the field. I use CodeFirst with Postgres and I had to mapped it that way: `builder.HasColumnType($"NUMERIC(5,2)")`. I don't know how SQLServer works, but you can try something like that.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I guess EF wasn't tracking the precision for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments of the question I set the precision using model builder in entity framework to match the precision of my database.

Thank you to everyone for helping me arrive at this answer.

**Code**

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Entity<TimeEntry>().Property(e => e.TimeWorked).HasPrecision(4, 2);
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 }
```